# Vbnet datatable fails to retrive us7ascii oracle data

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle, type-conversion

We have an application written in vb.net 4.5 that use ODBC driver to retrive data from an Oracle 10g database. The database character  set is set to us7ascii. We have tables that contains extended ascii characters (like for example ÄÄ or ÈÈ ). When we try to retrive data using the following code :

```
        Dim thisCN1 As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(connectionString)
        Dim szSql as string="select * from mytable"  
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim dataAdapter As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(szSql, thisCN1)
        dataAdapter.Fill(dt)
```

We have ?? characters instead of  ÄÄ or ÈÈ in columns that contains extended ascii characters.
In the select query we have a column ( for example COLUMN_A ) of type varchar2 that contains extended ascii characters ( like for example ÄÄ or ÈÈ ). When we inspect the resulted datatable we found a ? characters instead of ÄÄ or ÈÈ . We thought that the problem was in the conversion from us7ascii oracle datatype  to vbnet system.string that is 16bit unicode. varchar2 oracle columns seems to be mapped as system.string datacolumn type.

For further investigation , we have tried to get data using ADODB recordset. We have used the following code :

```
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim szSql as string="select * from mytable"  
    cn.ConnectionString = "connectionstring"
    cn.Open()
    rs.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
    rs.Open(szSql, cn)
    rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing
```

In the select query we have a column ( for example COLUMN_A ) of type varchar2 that contains extended ascii characters ( like for example ÄÄ or ÈÈ ). When we inspect the resulted recordset we found the correct characters ( ÄÄ or ÈÈ ).

Does anyone know how to tell the vbnet datatable to do not make any type conversion ?

Comment: The `US7ASCII` character set does not support the characters Ä or È.  You cannot (validly) store those characters in a `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, or `VARCHAR2` column in an Oracle database if that is the character set.  Is it possible for you to change the character set of the database to something that does properly encode all the characters you need to store?

Comment: Our application needs only to read data from database (database charset is us7ascii).

Comment: Our application needs only to read data from database (database charset is us7ascii).
If oracle client has NSL_LANG=us7ascii and Oracle database has charset=US7ascii , when the client sends data to database there are no data  conversions . The data are trasmitted as they are. We have to read data from database without any conversion made by Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter. The non converted data that are readen from db will be appear correctly ( without ??? ) in excel sheet because they exists in local pc codepage.

Comment: The sort of passthrough configuration you describe is both highly non-supported and highly non-recommended in addition to be very fragile.  Not every technology is even capable of being incorrectly configured so as to allow passthrough.  Are you really certain that you want to perpetuate an incorrect, unsupported, fragile architecture rather than correcting the root problem now before it's even harder to fix in the future?

Comment: We can not modify the software architecture . We  build the reporting part of the software. We have to read data from Oracle database and then put that data into an excel file. This is software is on production from many years and has been build by a big software  company. Also the committent is a big oil company .